# Get Value from key using linq

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have Dictionary  from string key i want to get Value of corresponding key using Linq

Comment: And if you have the key, why in the world do you want to use LINQ to get the value? Why not `var value = myDictionary["myKey"];` ?

Comment: Dictionary <string ,int> test=new Dictionary<string,int>();

Comment: The question still makes no sense. Never mind Linq, just describe what you already have and what outcome you want. Don't make the mistake of thinking you need to use a certain tool or pattern when that may not be the case.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Why do you want to get a value from a Dictionary using LINQ? You can just get the value using:

```
int value = dictionary[key];
```

You could use `Single`, but it's totally pointless and more code:

```
var keyValuePair = dictionary.Single(x => x.Key == key);
int value = keyValuePair.Value;
```

Comment: I agree. Using LINQ for this throws away O(1) performance for O(N). Totally pointless.

Comment: Why do I get the awful feeling that your Linq example just made it into some production code somewhere?

Comment: @Quick Joe Smith - I know. I think I've died a little inside.

Comment: so what if it made it into production code, what is wrong with it?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict `Using LINQ for this throws away O(1) performance for O(N).`

Comment: The first example throws the following error if the key doesn't exist: "System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary." You will need to use dictionary.ContainsKey(key) first or dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value) to check and extract the value in one lookup.

Answer (score 14):

Why use Linq for something that is built in?

```
var val = myDict[key];
```

Use Linq where it makes sense (querying collections), not for something that is already well handled by the `Dictionary` classes.

Comment: so what's wrong with LINQ.  Big deal if it's longer syntax, it's there to extend with more or diff LINQ next time and easy to read.  Sure accessing by key with [] is the least chars but who cares in this case.  So LINQ is slower querying a dictionary you say?   Anyone done any tests to prove that?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict - My point is that LINQ is not the answer for everything. Some things, like indexers, are language features that should be used instead of going around them using LINQ.

Comment: I agree it's not always the answer but it's very useful for a LOT.  I'd love to see a performance comparison between indexers and LINQ

Comment: also it's code preference to some point.  What I don't think is good is pepole talk about performance but there are no benchmarks or real tests to prove it in some cases.  If you're gonna talk about performance back it up with proof.  Until then it's just heir say.  I mean some things are obvious but when you start comparing stuff like LINQ to something else, then you really need to back it up is what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

returns the string value in this particular instance.

```
    Disctionary<int, string> CustomValues = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    CustomValues[int]; //CustomValues[key];
```

Answer (score 0):

**To Get the Value from the Dictionary Key**

```
Dictionary<int,string>dict=new Dictionary<int,string>();
dict.Add(1,"Maha");
dict.Add(2,"Malathi");
dict.Add(3,"Mithra");
dict.Add(4,"Saravana");

var val=dict.Where(x=>x.Key==key).Select(x=>x.Value);//get the value from dictionary where key=3
(or)
var val=dict[Key];//get the value for Dictionary key 3.
```

Output: Mithra